# is the distributive property for $2+ (x-1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, binary-operations

Does  the distributive property hold for a  formula having as form : $( a+(x-b))$?

For example, suppose $2+ (x-1).$

Applying the distributive property would be like

$ (2 + x) - (2 + 1) $

is this possible?

Comment: You can check such a claim by substituting an actual number for $x$ that produces an unequal value.  Here $x=1$ makes it particularly easy to check.

Comment: There is only one operation there: addition.  You need two in order to distribute.  Grouping symbols suggests an associative property.  Subtraction is just addition of inverses.

Answer (score 0):

The distributive property involves multiplication and addition, not addition alone.  It is not true that $(2+x)-1=(2+x)-(2+1)$.  Just try it.  The first is $x+1$ and the second is $x-1$